# Android UI Update

Tags: android, android-activity

What is the name of the Android function (part of the Activity class) that is used to update the UI (user interface) from a background thread?  Note that if we try to update the UI without using this function then Android will raise an exception.
Is it runOnUiThread() ? or it is something else. I do not get this right.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this when working on a background thread for example

```
((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    { 
         Toast.makeText(context, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         // Update the UI here basically
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you out!